# PHP add attribute to objects in foreach loop

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach, attributes

So my problem is - I've div with this kind of structure:

```
<div>
<strong> Value 1</strong>
<strong> Value 2</strong>
<strong> Value 3</strong>
</div>
```

It's a wordpress site, I've posts with slugs like - /value-1/ /value-2/ etc.
I need to use this wp function - wp_some_function(get_ID_by_slug('any-page')); and add attribute to each of those strong tags with that post id. So it would look like:

```
<div>
<strong id="2334"> Value 1</strong>
<strong id="34322"> Value 2</strong>
<strong id="2323"> Value 3</strong>
</div>
```

So basically I need to get content of each , replace spaces with dash, and add it in function I wrote above to get page ID, which I need to add as "id" attribute".

Comment: I only tried it with jquery, but didn't get too far, I used this code under click event    var kolek = $(this).text();
   var vards = kolek.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase(); to get proper slug, but then I realised that I won't be able to do it with jquery, searched through all google, but didn't find anything for me

Comment: you should edit your question to include what **all** you've tried, instead of putting it in a comment

Answer (score 1):

Try this or drive your code from it

```
<?php
    function ravs_postID($my_slug)
      $slug_to_get = str_replace(' ','-',$my_slug);
      $args=array(
       'name' => $slug_to_get,
       'post_type' => 'post',
       'post_status' => 'publish',
       'showposts' => 1,
       'caller_get_posts'=> 1
     );
     $my_posts = get_posts($args);
     if( $my_posts ) {
      return $my_posts[0]->ID;
     }
    }
    ?>
    <div>
     <strong id="<?php echo ravs_postID('Value 1'); ?>"> Value 1</strong>
     <strong id="<?php echo ravs_postID('Value 2'); ?>"> Value 2</strong>
     <strong id="<?php echo ravs_postID('Value 3'); ?>"> Value 3</strong>
    </div>
```

Comment: seriously, your handle as part of the function name?

Comment: Is anything wrong with code ? I don't understand what you trying to say.

Comment: A handle is a person’s online alias or shortened-name, often referred to as a ‘nickname’ or, from a systems perspective, ‘username’. **ravs** _postID